# Playing a silent movie with AVFoundation and keeping iPod music playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, mov

I have an app that plays silent Movies using AVFoundation. Is there a way to allow the music to play and your iPod (if you're playing music) to continue playing? If I play the movie will my iPod is on, the iPod pauses so the movie can play, and vice versa - if I try to replay the music while the movie is playing, the movie pauses. Basically, I want them to play continue playing seamlessly....

Let me know if you need applicable code to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, for standard AVAudioPlayer based sound in an app, managing the AVAudioSession is required to allow background music:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
```

But I can't tell you if that's the same as attempting to play encoded/compressed Video and encoded/compressed audio at the same time.

Comment: oh, and I would not actually use nil for the error, but you get the point. Also, if this does work, remember that your category options can frequently get reset by other inputs, like the phonecall, etc, so the true implementation requires reacting to things like AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, etc. It's all in the class reference.

Comment: Thanks @CH Buckingham. As of right now, I'm 95% percent sure you can't for mix AVAudio with Video, though you can with two audio sessions...